# Sticky or featured meta-topics

Tags: discussion, feature-request

IMO it would be good if ...

- [What are the attributes of a good question?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/882)
- [What are the attributes of a good answer?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/868)

... were more prominent, with some perma-link on the meta front page:

- For new users who first visit meta
- For other users, who want to find them easily in order to use them as targets of links in comments on the main board.

Do you agree, can they be, and will you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is a good idea.

No, we are a little bit limited in what we can do. I spent some time discussing this with other moderators yesterday. I don't want to comment more about how it will look until I have got my head around it properly.

Yes, we are working on it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a faq panel on the sidebar of http://meta.stackoverflow.com but that is specific to meta.so, because it is the network capital.

Comment: One platform I've seen ([Link](http://vanillaforums.org/)) lets a moderator mark a topic as 'sticky': a sticky topic is one whose location is always the top of the sorted list of topics (it also has a tag or border or background color that marks it as 'special'); the effect is similar to Google ads at the top of the search results: very visible/noticeable (though one can learn to tune them out) because they're the first results at the top of the very list which people are looking at (not a sidebar).

Comment: @chrisw yeah, not a fan of that approach

Comment: I have no other specific suggestion but apparently the mods have been discussing it.